# set DataSource for DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview

In class I have these two attributes:

```
public Dictionary<int, int> memCache { get; set; }
public Dictionary<int, MESIState> cacheStates { get; set; }
```

I use this code to join them:

```
cache1 = new MESICache(mainMemory);
var info = from a in cache1.memCache
           join b in cache1.cacheStates on a.Key equals b.Key
           select new { address = a.Key, value = a.Value, state = b.Value };
```

When I set this info variable as DataSource for DataGridView object, I don't see any output. But there are some warnings like:

```
Warning 2   The field 'MESI.Form1.addressDataGridViewTextBoxColumn' is never used   C:\Users\User\Path\MESI\MESI\Form1.Designer.cs  495 64  MESI
```

Obviously, I don't set data properly, but can't figure out how exactly I should do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if it works after calling `.ToList()` at the end of your LINQ:

```
var info = (from a in memCache
            join b in cacheStates on a.Key equals b.Key
            select new {address = a.Key, value = a.Value, state = b.Value}).ToList();

dataGridView1.DataSource = info;
```

When I try it without, and just bind the IEnumerable to a DataGridView, it doesn't show up.

As for the warning you're seeing, that *"addressDataGridViewTextBoxColumn is never used"*, you probably have a class-level variable in `Form1` that's unused, and the compiler is just informing you that you may have forgotten about it (and could potentially just remove it).